# Can I use methods in my controller in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method in my member model to determine if a member is an admin or not:

```
  def is_admin?; self.member_role.admin == true; end
```

How can I use that in my controller to find all users who arent admins?

My controller is already is pretty packed:

```
    @names = Member.where("fullname LIKE ?", "#{params[:letter]}%").order("fullname ASC").page(params[:page]).per(18)
```

Id like to not have to use reject{} in my views

Answer (score 2):

You can create a scope in your model like :

```
scope :non_admins, where(:admin => false)
```

And in your controller :

```
@names = Member.where("fullname LIKE ?", "#{params[:letter]}%").non_admins.order("fullname ASC").page(params[:page]).per(18)
```

Comment: The admin column is actually on a separate table called member_role so I cant use the :admin symbol

Comment: you can still use it through the association, like user.member_role.non_admins and set the scope there. Notice that a member_role model is most probably redundant. If you are setting roles, you should set them using a constant array in your User model.

Comment: I mean, how would I use the method I wrote in my member model, "is_artist?" in the scope? I've tried a couple things but keep getting undefined method errors

Comment: bump! and do you have a link to how to use a constant array in the user model? I should start using best practices

Comment: please, for clarity sake, make it a new question and i will reply there. in short it's like LIST = %w[one two three], but let's keep this in another post.

Answer (score 0):

The best way - using scope in your model [Ruby guides - scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Put your filters and orders in scope declaration and use scope in controller